# Insert single row data from a HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I have some sample data like this which is generated from database
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgnPP.jpg)

I want to insert just single row value by Assign button in the corresponding row
E.g. by clicking first-row assign button I want to insert 'CSE412', 'Artificial Intelligence', '3'
My problem is when I click any of assign button all of the data which is generated from a database are inserted into the database.
My try is

```
<?php
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_course");
    $stmt->execute();
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      $student_id = $_GET['id'];
      $course_id  = $row['id'];
?>
<form class="" action="" method="post">
<tr style="border-top: 1px solid #32383e;">
  <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['course_code']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['course_title']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['credit']; ?></td>
  <td>
    <?php
      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_course_enroll (student_id, course_id) VALUES ('$student_id', '$course_id')";
        $conn->exec($sql);
      }
    ?>
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Assign" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php
  }
  $conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, take that `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){ ... }` block outside of the `while()` loop because it's causing repeated `INSERT` operation. Now the question is, how do you insert a specific row data after clicking the corresponding *Assign* button? Here's the solution:

- Change your form's `action` attribute in the following way,

  ```
  <form ... action="?id=<?php echo $student_id; ?>&cid=<?php echo $course_id; ?>" ...>
  ```
- Assign a value in the `name` attribute of *Assign* button.

  ```
  <input type="submit" name="assign" value="Assign" class="btn btn-primary">
  ```
- And when the user hits the *Assign* button, store the corresponding row details in the following way,

  ```
  if (isset($_POST['assign'])){
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_course_enroll (student_id, course_id) VALUES (?,?)");
      $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->bindParam(2, $_GET['cid'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
      if($stmt->execute()){
          // INSERT operation successful
      }
  }
  ```

Here's the complete code,

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['assign'])){
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_course_enroll (student_id, course_id) VALUES (?,?)");
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $_GET['cid'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            // INSERT operation successful
        }
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_course");
    $stmt->execute();
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $student_id = $_GET['id'];
        $course_id  = $row['id'];
?>
    <form class="" action="?id=<?php echo $student_id; ?>&cid=<?php echo $course_id; ?>" method="post">
        <tr style="border-top: 1px solid #32383e;">
            <td><?php echo ++$i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['course_code']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['course_title']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['credit']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" name="assign" value="Assign" class="btn btn-primary">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
<?php
    }
  $conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: @ShafikShaon, Here I'm assuming that *student_id* column is of integer type and *course_id* column is of string type.

Comment: Problem arise this will not insert the data redirect to another page

Comment: @ShafikShaon What do you mean by *data redirect to another page*? The form will submit the data to whichever page it's currently in.

Comment: suppose my form is in  course.php file .From index.php I go to the course.php file. After form submit it will automatically go to index.php

Comment: @ShafikShaon It doesn't matter from which page you end up in *course.php* page. However, if you entire form and corresponding processing logic is in *course.php* page, then change your form's `action` attribute in the following way, `action="course.php?sid=<?php echo $student_id; ?>&cid=<?php echo $course_id; ?>"`

Comment: @ShafikShaon I've updated my answer just a little bit, you should use `id` instead of `sid` to send/fetch student's id. The reason being you're processing the form details on the same page, otherwise `$student_id = $_GET['id'];` statement would throw error once you submit the form.

Comment: my course_id also an int I change this but throw an error
$stmt->bind_param("ii", (int)$_GET['id'], (int)$_GET['cid']);

Comment: @ShafikShaon What error are you getting? By the way, from the screenshot it seems course id (*CSE412*, *CSE413*, etc.) is of type string.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in D:\xampp\htdocs\Project\sadia\assigncourse.php:29 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\Project\sadia\assigncourse.php on line 29

Comment: @ShafikShaon Ah, that's my mistake. I've updated my answer and changed mysqli APIs to PDO APIs.

Comment: Great Solution. This problem will kill my 12 hours